# How to pause animated sprite animation in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, cocos2d-x

I want to pause/unpause animation for particular sprite when proper message appears. I would do this by `CCNode::stopAllActions()` but it cancels all the animations which are then meant to set up again. I just want to do it in a quick pause/unpasue way. Anyone have a clue for efficitne way on this subject?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[yourSprite pauseSchedulerAndActions]
```

and to resume

```
[yourSprite resumeSchedulerAndActions]
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer didn't work for me? Any body know why? This worked for me

```
#import "CCActionManager.h"

[[CCActionManager sharedManager] pauseAllActionsForTarget:spriteObj];
[[CCActionManager sharedManager] resumeAllActionsForTarget:spriteObj];
```